# F# JSON Type Provider, do not serialize null values

Tags: json, f#, f#-data

**Background**

I am using the FSharp.Data JSON Type Provider with a sample that has an array of objects that may have different properties. Here is an illustrative example:

```
[<Literal>]
let sample = """
    { "input": [
        { "name": "Mickey" },
        { "year": 1928 }
       ] 
    }
"""
type InputTypes = JsonProvider< sample >
```

The JSON Type Provider creates an Input type which has both an Optional Name and an Optional Year property. That works well.

**Problem**

When I try to pass an instance of this to the web service, I do something like this:

```
InputTypes.Root(
    [|
        InputTypes.Input(Some("Mouse"), None)
        InputTypes.Input(None, Some(2028))
    |]
)
```

The web service is receiving the following and choking on the nulls.

```
{
  "input": [
    {
      "name": "Mouse",
      "year": null
    },
    {
      "name": null,
      "year": 2028
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I Tried**

I find that this works:

```
InputTypes.Root(
    [|
        InputTypes.Input(JsonValue.Parse("""{ "name": "Mouse" }"""))
        InputTypes.Input(JsonValue.Parse("""{ "year": 2028 }"""))
    |]
)
```

It sends this:

```
{
  "input": [
    {
      "name": "Mouse"
    },
    {
      "year": 2028
    }
  ]
}
```

However, on my real project, the structures are larger and would require a lot more conditional JSON string building. It kind of defeats the purpose.

**Questions**

- Is there a way to cause the JSON Type Provider to not serialize null properties?
- Is there a way to cause the JSON Type Provider to not serialize empty arrays?

As a point of comparison, the Newtonsoft.JSON library has a [NullValueHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) attribute.

Comment: The way I read [JsonParser.parseValue()](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/bb8a5ec828a47cdd9554f284efa5cb341bcecb5a/src/Json/JsonValue.fs#L178) and [JsonParser.parseArray()](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/bb8a5ec828a47cdd9554f284efa5cb341bcecb5a/src/Json/JsonValue.fs#L276), it looks like you cannot currently change the behavior when the parser encounters null properties or empty arrays in a JSON string.  I think the project will need a PR to add that behavior, unless I completely misread the source code.  If I can get my germ of an idea working locally, I will open one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to get the JSON formatting in F# Data to drop the `null` fields - I think the type does not clearly distinguish between what is `null` and what is missing.

You can fix that by writing a helper function to drop all `null` fields:

```
let rec dropNullFields = function
  | JsonValue.Record flds ->
      flds 
      |> Array.choose (fun (k, v) -> 
        if v = JsonValue.Null then None else
        Some(k, dropNullFields v) )
      |> JsonValue.Record
  | JsonValue.Array arr -> 
      arr |> Array.map dropNullFields |> JsonValue.Array
  | json -> json
```

Now you can do the following and get the desired result:

```
let json = 
  InputTypes.Root(
      [|
          InputTypes.Input(Some("Mouse"), None)
          InputTypes.Input(None, Some(2028))
      |]
  )

json.JsonValue |> dropNullFields |> sprintf "%O"
```